# Передвижение объекта Touch.position

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Введение: 2D проект, в котором есть два Sprite. Первый передвигается в позицию касанию на экран (Touch), Второй же перемещается/отдаляется к Первому. Все перемещения делаются через `transform.position`.

Суть проблемы: Второй передвигается с заданной скоростью без нареканий, но не Первый.

Во-первых: т.к. это 2D, то я фиксирую Z-ось в FixedUpdate, потому что при таче происходит изменение этой самой оси. (Аналогично происходит и если тач заменить на позицию курсора - улетает по Z...). Как это можно решить, чтобы не фиксировать Z-ось?

Во-вторых: само передвижение:

```cs
Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
Vector3 touchpos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(newVector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0f));
touchpos.Normalize();
float moveposX = touchpos.x * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
float moveposY = touchpos.y * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
PlayerObj.transform.position = PlayerObj.transform.position + new Vector3(moveposX, moveposY,0f);
```

Передвижение слишком медленное. Да, можно добавить скорости (speed), но Второй объект, который следует/отдаляется за Первым имеет такую же скорость и такой код

```cs
Vector3 delta = transform.position - Player.position;
delta.Normalize();
if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, Player.transform.position) < Distance && Catch.CurrentCatch == "Enemy")
{
    Enemy.transform.position += -delta * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
}
else
{
    Enemy.transform.position += delta * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
}
```

Если использовать `Input.GetAxis`, то управление на клавиатуре оказывается ровно таким, как и у Второго объекта - точно такая же скорость.

Как можно решить проблему привязки Z-оси и скорости передвижения объекта управляемого через позицию тача/мыши?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить `Vector3 touchpos =` на `Vector2 touchpos =`.

`Vector3 delta` кстати тоже кривая.

Comment: @0xdb, гонишь! Может я и не стал объяснять разницу Normslize Vector3 и Vector2... в падлу, он бы и сам мог посмотреть. Но всё же это решение его проблемы. Ещё и намёк на другую.

Comment: Он и так написал свой вопрос таким образом, что никто отвечать не захотел.